# Using Design:attribute in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I currently have an aura component with which has a design:attribute as an input for when the component is used in a community to help the admin configure it. I would like to use that inputted information inside of a visual force page.

Effectively, an admin would add the twitter handle they would like to see in the community and this field is added to the twitter URL inside of the visualforce page:

`<design:attribute name="twitterhandle" label="Twitter Handle" />`

I also include this attribute in the .cmp file

`<aura:attribute name="twitterhandle" type="String" access="global" />`

and inside of the visual force page I have a URL which I would like to append the inputted string to

`<a class="twitter-timeline" data-link-color="#19CF86" href="https://twitter.com/ + {TwitterHandle}">Tweets by twitter</a>`

Any assistance in helping me take the twitter handle from the design attribute and applying it to the URL in the visual force page is greatly appreciated!

Regards,
James

Answer (score 2):

You can embeed the vf page inside lightning component using IFrame and pass twitter handle as a url parameter and update the href attribute in js of VF page.

Example

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.widget}"/>

    <a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitterFeedContainer" data-link-color="#19CF86">Tweets by twitter</a>

    <script>
        const twitterHandle = "https://twitter.com/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.twitterHandle}";
        const twitterFeedContainer = document.getElementById("twitterFeedContainer");
        twitterFeedContainer.setAttribute("href", twitterHandle);
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="twitterHandle"
                    type="String"
                    default="anmolgkv"/>
    <aura:attribute name="width"
                    type="String"
                    default="1000px"/>
    <aura:attribute name="height"
                    type="String"
                    default="800px"/>

    <aura:attribute name="visualForceDomain" 
                    type="String"
                    default="https://drive-fun-3391-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com"/>

    <!-- Pass the twitter handle as url parameter -->
    <iframe src="{!v.visualForceDomain + '/apex/TwitterFeed?twitterHandle=' + v.twitterHandle}" width="{!v.width}" height="{!v.height}"/>
</aura:component>
```

> Note: I have added [twitter script](https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) in widget static resource